# Requires not loading images in CRA

Tags: reactjs, typescript, require, loading-image

**Hi**

I am currently trying to display elements of a list in react and I'm not able to load images using *require*.
I am using CRA and haven't changed webpack.config.js.

**The list**

```
import img1 from "../../assets/work-in-progress.png";

const projects = [
    {
        id: 1,
        image_path: img1,
        title: "t1",
        category: "testing"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        image_path: require("../../assets/work-in-progress.png"),
        title: "t2",
        category: "testing"
    },
]
```

**How I am displaying the images**

```
<img src={ entry.image_path } alt="Project's" className="rounded" />
```

Currently, the first image is being displayed correctly but the second doesn't load.

I have already tried using `src={ "" + entry.image_path }` and got the same result.

Comment: `image_path: img1` this should work. Please make sure you've uploaded your images in public folder.

Comment: Yes, that works. The problem is in the second element of the array, the image doesn't load with the 'require' but does so with the import statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think your path isn't correct. It's working in my end. Here is the working [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-ives-kkbv7?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Yes, that is also working on my end, the problem is in the second element of the array.

Comment: I have however edited your sandbox to add the second element as I wrote it locally as you can see [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-ritchie-33x8u) and weirdly enough it worked. I guess the problem is in some local configuration ?? I am using CRA